# how to get specific details from zookeeper and not all info that isn't required

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

we have kafka cluster, version is 0.10

we can capture only the `segment.bytes` value from zookeeper

we did the following approach

```
zookeeper-shell kafka1:2181 get /config/topics/topic_test                                                           
Connecting to kafka1:2181

WATCHER::

WatchedEvent state:SyncConnected type:None path:null
{"version":1,"config":{"segment.bytes":"10737555","retention.bytes":"104857600"}}
cZxid = 0xb30a00000038
ctime = Mon Jun 29 11:42:30 GMT 2020
mZxid = 0xb311000089d7
mtime = Fri Jul 24 08:04:38 GMT 2020
pZxid = 0xb30a00000038
cversion = 0
dataVersion = 9
aclVersion = 0
ephemeralOwner = 0x0
dataLength = 81
numChildren = 0
```

we can see from above that also many details are printed from output

I want to know if we can run the zookeeper-shell  in order to get only the `"retention.bytes":"104857600"` details

maybe I am using the path of the topic instead other path ?

so the expected results should be

example

```
zookeeper-shell kafka1:2181 get /config/topics/topic_test                                                           
Connecting to kafka1:2181

WATCHER::

retention.bytes":"104857600
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zookeeper-shell` cannot parse JSON. It only prints the binary data that is stored in the ZNodes

You will need to write parsing code around that command to extract that data